# WP7 - Performance and Memory issue

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-phone

I have an application and having memory issues. Everytime I navigate between pages memory usage is increasing.

My Application includes three page:

- **MainPage** *Panaroma* page with 1 menu + 3 dynamic (reading feeds)
  panaroma items
- **HistoryPage** another *Panaroma* Page (3panaroma items) with static
  Textblocks and 2-3 15kb images
- **AboutPage** Static *Pivot*(2items) Page with Textblocks and 1 15kb
  image.

**Situation 1:**

- When Application loaded it takes 37mb memory.
- Then, I navigate to History page and come back to the main page Memory usage increases to 89mb.
- Then I navigate again to history page and come back now it becomes 109mb. Everytime I navigate memory usage incrising.

**Situation 2:**

- When Application loaded it takes 37mb memory.
- Then, I navigate to About page and come back to the main page Memory usage increases to 54mb.
- Then I navigate to history page and come back now it becomes 94mb.

What are the causes for this problem? Those contents are static texts and I don't use any Isolated storage, tombstoning or anything. How can I make it to remove cache when the user navigates from the page.

Thank you inadvance. Please keep in mind and excuse me I am really noob at coding stuffs like that.

Navigation button in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HistoryPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

HistoryPage.xaml

```
        <controls:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="backgrounds/PanoramaBackground.jpg"  />
        </controls:Panorama.Background>

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem CacheMode="BitmapCache">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="hede" Margin="12,0,12,0" Grid.Row="1" Width="432" >
                <StackPanel Width="432">
                    <Image Height="220" Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" Source="images/logo.png" Width="172" Margin="0,30,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
    </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="history" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image x:Name="tarih" Source="images/history.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Width="380" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
    </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item three-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="achievements" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock ....
    </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item three-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="contact" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
            <StackPanel>
                <my:Map x:Name="stad" Grid.Row="1"
                        CredentialsProvider=.....
                        LogoVisibility="Collapsed" ScaleVisibility="Visible"
                        Center=..... ZoomLevel="15"
                        CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" ZoomBarVisibility="Visible" Width="380" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <my:Pushpin Location="....." Content="....."></my:Pushpin>
                </my:Map>
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
                    <TextBlock ....
    </StackPanel>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

HistoryPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class HistoryPage: PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public HistoryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can spot, you're using a Bing Map control directly in a panorama control. This is not encouraged. You should see if that's the cause of the high memory use.

Comment: Yes Claus, I guess that was the problem. I have removed the bing map and background. Now memory usage is ok. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess (without seeing your code), you're generating the (dynamic) Panorama Items every time you refresh the main page, causing the extra load.

Basically:

- 1st display of mainpage: 3 dynamic panorama items.
- 2nd display of mainpage: 6 dynamic panorama items.
- 3rd display of mainpage: 9 dynamic panorama items.
- ...

Comment: Ok I removed those 3 dynamic feeds. Memory usage is 27mb at start but when I navigate to history page and come back it goes to 89mb again. I clicked on history once again and memory usage increased to 105mb. I think the problem is in the historypage. How can I make it to remove this page from memory usage?